# magento database

Tags: magento

i need found in magento database information about users: description , status (login or not).
Where i can find this information in data base?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find this out about the current user, or about other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento uses an [EAV structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) so finding information can be tricky.

There is a slightly out-of-date but useful overview diagram here:
http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/magento_v116-database_diagram.pdf

To answer part of your question, I don't think Magento stores the login status in the database, that would be stored in the session.  Other details like description/username will be in one of the entity value tables.

Comment: A guy named Goodwin seems to maintain a list of REALLY GOOD diagrams here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial I found about EAV in Magento:

http://fishpig.co.uk/2010/06/07/magento-database-structure-eav/

You can also see a diagram of the Magento database by Googling Magento Database.